# Laradock - Service 'php-fpm' failed to build

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

Info:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Docker version: 20.10.6
- Commit: 63fc1fd
- Project versions:

  - Laravel 5.8.33
  - Vue 2.6.10

My Laravel docker environment stopped working today.
After several tries I finally deleted all images and tried to rebuild environemt.
I get the same error:

```
+ apt-get install -yqq apt-utils libzip-dev zip unzip
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ERROR: Service 'php-fpm' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -xe;     apt-get update -yqq &&     pecl channel-update pecl.php.net &&     apt-get install -yqq       apt-utils       libzip-dev zip unzip &&       docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip &&       docker-php-ext-install zip &&       php -m | grep -q 'zip'' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

[image]

Here is the code of my [php-fpm Docker file](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/63fc1fde44cc00aacb89511a441cb83685e8010c/php-fpm/Dockerfile).
Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

in Dockerfile

you can add:

FROM composer AS composer

COPY . /app
RUN rm composer.lock && composer install 
--optimize-autoloader 
--no-interaction 
--no-progress 
--ignore-platform-reqs

RUN apk add --no-cache php 
php7-common 
php7-fpm 
php7-pdo 
php7-opcache 
php7-zip \

Comment: Can you please explain what does this code do? And in which point you suggest to add it?

Comment: this code to install dependencies or libraries, may i see your Dockerfile code

Comment: atau cukup tambahkan ini di Dockerfile Anda

RUN apk add --no-cache php
php7-common
php7-fpm

Comment: Docker file: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/63fc1fde44cc00aacb89511a441cb83685e8010c/php-fpm/Dockerfile

Comment: try using this Dockerfilefile
it runs on my laradock

Answer (score -1):

did you add

RUN apk add --no-cache php 
php7-common 
php7-fpm \

Comment: Where exactly, in `php-fpm/Dockerfile`?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
FROM composer AS composer

COPY . /app
RUN rm composer.lock && composer install \
  --optimize-autoloader \
  --no-interaction \
  --no-progress \
  --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN chmod 777 -R storage

FROM alpine:3.13
LABEL Maintainer="Diki Rahman <diki@sawala.tech>"

RUN apk add --no-cache php \
    php7-common \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-zip \
    php7-phar \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-cli \
    php7-curl \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-fileinfo \
    php7-json \
    php7-xml \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-dom \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-pdo_sqlite \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-pecl-redis \
    nginx supervisor curl

COPY docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY docker/php-fpm/fpm-pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY docker/php/php.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/timezone.ini

COPY docker/supervisord/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/backend

RUN chown -R nginx.nginx /var/www/html && \
  chown -R nginx.nginx /run && \
  chown -R nginx.nginx /var/lib/nginx && \
  chown -R nginx.nginx /var/log/nginx

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY --chown=nginx --from=composer /app /var/www/html
COPY --chown=nginx --from=composer /app /var/www/backend

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

HEALTHCHECK --timeout=10s CMD curl --silent --fail http://127.0.0.1:8080/fpm-ping
```

Comment: Do you mean replace existing Dockerfile? Or add this code in some place? I would be grateful to have more clarity about this solution. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this Dockerfile? It is very different from the one in the repository: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/php-fpm/Dockerfile